# Почему не доходят данные в Tcp/ip приложении?

Tags: c#, tcp-ip

Есть прикладное клиент-серверное приложение, основанное на сокетах tcp/ip. Данные отправляются и получаются спокойно с любыми компами, кроме одного, данные оттуда не отправляются, будь тот хоть клиентом, хоть сервером, а получаются спокойно. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: В чём угодно. У меня есть такой же сервер, правда легаси (win2003, давно снятый с поддержки) и ПО на сокетах мы сами писали. С другими серверами нормально работает, а этот толи от старости уже совсем плох, толи реестр слишком сильно тюнинговали... Но и с новыми может быть что угодно. Прямо говоря, шансы на то, что вы решите подобный вопрос здесь на so невелики.

Comment: Это похоже не файерволл, судя по направлению: исходящие обычно всегда разрешены.

Comment: Винду переустанови